# Office manifest passes with validate-office-addin but fails when uploading to Office 365

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-js

I am trying to add a control button to my add-in. I have not changed most of the file, so am only including selected part of my manifest. Even while second Control is uncommented, the manifest passes according to validate-office-addin, but when trying to upload to Office 365 for testing, I am told my manifest is not valid. Been banging my head against this for a few hours now and would appreciate some help.

```
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton">
              <Label resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
              </Action>
            </Control>
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.RefreshButton">
              <Label resid="Contoso.RefreshButton.Label" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="Contoso.RefreshButton.Label" />
                <Description resid="Contoso.RefreshButton.Tooltip" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                <FunctionName>refreshAllReports</FunctionName>
              </Action>
            </Control>
```

Comment: There is a warning somewhere in the docs that says Add-In commands are not supported for Content Add-Ins, but this just has a taskpane so it should not be considered one. Does anyone know how Office is determining whether you're a content add-in or not?

Comment: Found the issue, was a typo somewhere lower down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a typo lower down in the manifest